# Как изменить высоту секции?

Tags: css

Есть секция высотой 100vh и min-height: 900px. Если смотреть с мобильного высота которого меньше 900px то секция получается больше высоты экрана. Как сделать чтобы при высоте меньше 900px секция была 100vh, но при горизонтальной ориентации был min-height.

Если не делать min-height то контент при малой высоте экрана будет вылезать на другие секции.

Что можно сделать в данной ситуации ?

https://anton-one.github.io/vh2/

Answer (score 0):

```
.section{
    height: 900px;
}
@media (max-height: 900px){
    .section{
        height:100vw;
    }
}
```

`@media` проверяет, является ли ширина экрана более 900 пикселов и применяет внутренние изменения, если да

А так же можно использовать `@media (max-width: 1100px){}`, если Вам вдруг понадобится проверить экран пользователя на ширину